# How to Remove Linux Downloaded and Extracted files in C: drive?

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, delete, unetbootin

I was trying to dual boot Linux Mint Cinnamon with my Windows 10 PC.
I used Unetbootin to install linux mint cinnamon iso file. I used the hard drive type installation in which the only hard drive in the option was C: drive.

The Unetbootin installer completed successfully. Now I want to remove every of those linux mint files from C: drive.

I have tried System Restore twice. I also get a message saying system restore was successful but still my Linux files are not removed at all.
I have tried manually deleting using Date modified and Date created but wasn't very successful using that.

PS: Would reset my PC work? would it remove Linux files from my C: ?

Please Help.
Thank you.

**Update:**
While trying to install Linux through USB, somehow my windows file got effected. My PC was not booting to the desktop screen. It always came to a blue screen that said

> Your device ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you.The image is included along with an error image that I also saw in my PC.
> [image: Blue screen not booting]
> [image: Error seem]

This happened **every single time** I restarted it. I know that only my C drive was effected because I booted using a Linux OS from a USB and my rest of the files were fine.

After 3 hours of panicking and trying out reset my pc (which failed), system restore (which was successful but still couldn't boot my pc), some scans from cmd terminal (which gave msg - Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.), I resigned myself that I would have to take it up to a technician.

As a last ditch effort, I tried System Restore at a later date than my previous restore points. It WORKED!! I don't know why that did and the other didn't (even though I had NOT installed linux in any of the restore points) but I was crazy in relief! My windows is back to normal. I am very grateful for it.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what you mean. Files in the Windows C:\ drive? Open CMD and run DIR. Then copy'n'paste the text

Answer (score 0):

Just as Microsoft Windows has no microsoft windows uninstaller that uninstalls Microsoft Windows, Linux has no Linux uninstaller.

You need to do some windows disk management thing to remove the Linux partition.

Comment: Could you clarify further please ? As in what exactly can I do to my C: for removing linux without corrupting my normal windows OS ?

Comment: Would reset my PC work? Resetting by keeping my doc and files ?

Comment: I don't know, you are asking about windows software now. I'm not familiar with it.  find a windows expert.

Answer (score 0):

From the [UNetbootin wiki](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes):

> Hard Disk Install Mode
>
> If you provide a LiveCD iso file, such as the Ubuntu desktop iso, to UNetbootin and use the hard disk install mode, the resulting install will NOT be a full, standard hard drive installation. Rather, you are simply booting into the live environment, the same way as if you had booted from a live CD or a live USB, except it's being loaded from your hard disk instead. This is often referred to as a "frugal install", as it doesn't install a dedicated bootloader and doesn't make a separate partition, but rather piggybacks off the existing OS's bootloader and installs the files for the live environment inside the existing partition. For details about the boot process, see [How UNetbootin Works](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/howitworks).

If this is exactly what you did, then there might be two main categories of "Linux files" on your Windows C: drive.

- the Mint Cinnamon ISO image and any files required to boot it
- any "personal files" related to your user account on Linux, and possibly to any actions you did using Linux.

UNetbootin might be able to uninstall the former, but the latter will be entirely your own responsibility. If you need help in identifying the files created by Linux, please edit your question to show the root directory of your C:\ drive, as suggested in the comments by @roaima.

(Analogy: even if you uninstall Microsoft Office, it will not delete every single `.doc` and `.docx` file from your system, since those files are not part of Office: they are **your files**, not the application's.)